# Alignment issue with Bootstrap radio group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, lotus-notes, bootstrap-modal

I am finding weird problem in alignment and unable to find what may causing this.

Here is how it looks, After first radio group there is big gap but it gets OK between second and third and rest of the radio.

[image]

Here is my code,

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
             <label for="top_Body_Mech" class="col-md-6 control-label">Body mechanics when lifting, carrying, reaching or pulling.</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Body_Mech"   value="Excellent">Excellent</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Body_Mech"   value="Concern">Concern</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Body_Mech"   value="None">None</label>
            </div>
             <label for="top_Maintain_Contact" class="col-md-6 control-label">Maintain 3 points of contact.</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Maintain_Contact"   value="Excellent">Excellent</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Maintain_Contact"   value="Concern">Concern</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Maintain_Contact"   value="None">None</label>
            </div>  
            <label for="top_Eyes_Work" class="col-md-6 control-label">Eyes on work or path.</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Eyes_Work"   value="Excellent">Excellent</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Eyes_Work"   value="Concern">Concern</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Eyes_Work"   value="None">None</label>
            </div>      
            <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Pace of work or movement.</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Pace_Work"   value="Excellent">Excellent</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Pace_Work"   value="Concern">Concern</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Pace_Work"   value="None">None</label>
            </div>      
            <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Obtain assistance.</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Obt_Assist"   value="Excellent">Excellent</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Obt_Assist"   value="Concern">Concern</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Obt_Assist"   value="None">None</label>
            </div>      
            <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Clear of pinch points.</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Pinch"   value="Excellent">Excellent</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Pinch"   value="Concern">Concern</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Pinch"   value="None">None</label>
            </div>      
            <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Clear of sharp edges.</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Edge"   value="Excellent">Excellent</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Edge"   value="Concern">Concern</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Edge"   value="None">None</label>
            </div>      
            <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Clear of “line of fire”.</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Fire"   value="Excellent">Excellent</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Fire"   value="Concern">Concern</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Fire"   value="None">None</label>
            </div>      
            <label class="col-md-6 control-label">Clear of hot surfaces or materials.</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Surface"   value="Excellent">Excellent</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Surface"   value="Concern">Concern</label><label class="form-radio form-normal form-text form-success "><input type="radio" name="top_Clear_Surface"   value="None">None</label>
            </div>      
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap uses a 12 column layout and you are using 3x col-md-6 within one row. This might be part of the issue. Please add the final HTML output from your code to your question.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten Added

Comment: Even if I use two cols with col-md-6 still same results.